# ASP and &apos; does not work

Tags: asp.net

I am not an ASP expert, just trying to help a friend.

It the past, HTML,I use `&apos;` for apostrophes in text.

Using the following it renders fine in Firefox but incorrect in IE 7.

```
asp:LinkButton ID="AceFrehley95Button" Text="Ace Frehley &apos; 95" OnCommand="lbtnSubMenu_Command" CommandArgument="AceFrehley95.wmv" Runat="Server"
```

In Firefox it renders: Ace Frehley '95

In IE 7 it renders: Ace Frehley &apos 95

How do I make IE render what Firefox does......

Jason

Comment: Surrounded your text with the code option so you could have the ";" in there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HTML doesn't actually have a `&apos;` entity. A lot of browsers support it (probably because it *is* a part of XHTML), but "officially" it doesn't exist. You should use `&#39;` instead.

Comment: +1. Also of course there's no need to escape the apostrophe in that particular example; the need for apos escapes only arises when you are (or might be) using single quotes to delimit attribute values. (Text='fish &#39;n&#39; chips')

Answer (score 2):

You could also try:

```
&rsquo;
```

Which renders as:

’

Comment: thx for the help! You saved my day &apos; didnt worked inside javascript calls...but your version did! :)

Answer (score -2):

Unless you are a typography purist,

```
   &acute;
```

may be close enough.

Comment: If you copy-paste C++ code from a web page, where the author has used  `&acute;`, the code won't compile, but it will not be easy to see where the problem is.