# is XmlFormat() always better than htmlEditFormat()?

Tags: xml, security, coldfusion

Saw a comment today at: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2004-Escaping-Form-Values-Understanding-The-ColdFusion-htmlEditFormat-Life-Cycle.htm by [Rick Osborne](http://twitter.com/rickosborneorg/)

> I've started moving my students from
>   `htmlEditFormat` over to `xmlFormat`. As
>   you said, it catches more characters,
>   but it's also useful for pure XML and
>   is faster to type. I haven't been able
>   to come up with a compelling reason to
>   stick with htmlEditFormat.

Should we all start using `XmlFormat()`?  Can you think of a "compelling reason" other than maybe slightly slower in performance?

Comment: Ha!  That guy is full of it.  What a n00b.

(And by that guy I mean me.  I've never been quoted on SO before.  Twisted.)

Comment: @Rick, you don't mind being quoted right? :)  I wonder if we should all make the switch to xmlFormat() because of your comment.

Comment: I don't mind at all. To be honest, it's not my idea. I saw an allusion to it in a slides by Pete Freitag. Looking back through his blog,  it looks like he's been advocating it since at least 2007.

Comment: I've not used CF, but it talking about escaping “high ASCII characters in the range 128-255” makes it sound like it really doesn't understand what ASCII and Unicode are, and may mangle your characters if you use an encoding other than ISO-8859-1. Like PHP's `htmlentities()` without `$charset= 'utf-8'` as compared to the usually-preferable `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: Is there an example post on using XMLformat available?

Comment: @justasying just use it where you'd use HtmlEditFormat()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** the below answer is no longer relevant. What i've noticed by using XMLFormat() over HTMLEditFormat() is that IE doesn't interpret the `&apos;` and thus causing havoc.

in my opinion, if it catches more (such as single quotes that Jason Dean pointed out) thus making your app safer, then i'll eat the performance hit. in all reality, how much of a performance hit could it possible be... 1 or 2ms?

in the upcoming cfwheels 1.1 release, i added an h() method that was a wrapper for the htmleditformat() method. after reading both ben's and this post, i'm going to be switching it over to use XMLFormat() instead.

Comment: Hmm.. you're right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609166/asp-and-apos-does-not-work so... back to `htmlEditFormat()`?

Comment: Yes, we had the same issue we are back to htmlEditFormat() is there a reason to NOT use htmlEditFormat() or were people just moving to xmlformat() because it was NEW?

Comment: In at least some versions of CF, htmlEditFormat didn't escape ampersands that were part of some entities. See https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3040920, closed fixed in 9.0.1. We used a simple replaceList function instead.

Comment: Is there any example of something that `htmleditformat()` change that `xmlformat()` does not?